# Pandas - Guarantee Column Existence Post Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that may or not include some states.

I want to pivot the table and then sort by the sum of the Count column values by state. This is a simplified example.

```
# Set DataFrame.
data = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['Run', 'Run', 'Wait', 'Unknown'],
                     'Count': [3, 4, 5, 6],
                     'ID': [3, 4, 4, 6]})
print('Original DF.\n', data)

# Pivot.
data = pd.pivot_table(data, values='Count', columns='State', index='ID', fill_value=0,
                      aggfunc='sum')
print('\nPivoted.\n', data)

# Sort
data = data.sort_values(['Run', 'Wait', 'Unknown'], ascending=False)
print('\nSorted.\n', data)
```

Here all is well as all of the expected states exist.

```
Original DF.
      State  Count  ID
0      Run      3   3
1      Run      4   4
2     Wait      5   4
3  Unknown      6   6

Pivoted.
 State  Run  Unknown  Wait
ID
3        3        0     0
4        4        0     5
6        0        6     0

Sorted.
 State  Run  Unknown  Wait
ID
4        4        0     5
3        3        0     0
6        0        6     0
```

But had we started with

```
# Set dataframe.
data = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['Run', 'Run', 'Wait', 'Wait'],
```

There would not be an 'Unknown' state to sort by, and an error. Further, this is a simplified example, and I do more work on these than just sorting.

I know I can do many things like check for the column and add it after the Pivot, and I can add Nan Vals with the state 'Unknown' prior to pivot, but this seems a common enough issue there should be a better solution.

Further, this seems a natural use of Pandas Categorical DType, but I've been unable to make this work for me. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

BTW: Here's what I'm doing currently.

```
for col in ['Run', 'Wait', 'Unknown']:
    if col not in data.columns:
        data[col] = 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a `MultiIndex`?

```
# List of all possible states
states = ['Run', 'Unknown', 'Wait']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([data['ID'].unique(), states], names=['ID', 'State'])

data = data.set_index(['ID', 'State']).reindex(idx).fillna(0)
pd.pivot_table(data, values='Count', columns='State', index='ID', fill_value=0,
                      aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: I will play with this and get back to you. It's less obvious (reading wise) than I would like, but I'm sure sufficient.

Comment: This is working for me unless I add `margins=True` to the pivot. Any idea why Pandas errors?  `File "...site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py", line 333, in _generate_marginal_results
    table_pieces.append(Series(margin[key], index=[all_key]))
KeyError: 'Run' `